# Check datatypes in where clause using DacFX SqlCodeAnalysisRule

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-project, dacpac, dac

I am trying to write a SqlCodeAnalysisRule rule to check comparison operators in a where clause to ensure that both sides are of the same data type for sargability. However, I am having an extremely hard time trying to figure out what the datatype actually is from the ScriptDom ColumnReferenceExpression object. I have spent a couple of days researching this, and have gotten really nowhere. Hopefully, someone can help.

This becomes much more complex when you refer to stored procedures and functions that can contain multiple select statements. Or even a view with multiple sub selects or unions. I have seen this answer [Get DataType of computed column from dacpac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259640/get-datatype-of-computed-column-from-dacpac) but it does not address how to get from the column inside a select back to the desired table.

Here is the Analyze for my rule as it stands now:

```
    public override IList<SqlRuleProblem> Analyze(SqlRuleExecutionContext ruleExecutionContext)
    {
        var problems = new List<SqlRuleProblem>();
        var sqlObj = ruleExecutionContext.ModelElement;

        try
        {
            if (sqlObj != null)
            {
                var children = sqlObj.GetChildren(DacQueryScopes.All);

                var fragment = ruleExecutionContext.ScriptFragment;

                var selectStatementVisitor = new SelectStatementVisitor();
                fragment.Accept(selectStatementVisitor);

                foreach (var select in selectStatementVisitor.Statements)
                {
                    var query = select.QueryExpression as QuerySpecification;
                    if(query != null && query.WhereClause != null)
                    {
                        var booleanComparisonVisitor = new BooleanComparisonVisitor();
                        query.WhereClause.Accept(booleanComparisonVisitor);

                        foreach (var comparison in booleanComparisonVisitor.Statements)
                        {
                            var refColumn = comparison.FirstExpression as ColumnReferenceExpression;
                            // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO INSPECT THE DATATYPE OF FirstExpression AND COMPARE IT TO THE DATATYPE OF the SecondExpression 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: PROPERLY LOG THIS ERROR
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            //throw;
        }

        return problems;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am going to post the solution I came up with although it is not 100% accurate. The problem with it not being 100% accurate is because of an issue with the DacFX api, and the fact that it does not allow built in functions to be queried. While not 100%,this has proven to be pretty decently accurate. I skip out on any I am unsure of (return null), and will have to rely on scanning the plan cache for implicit conversions.

```
[ExportCodeAnalysisRule(DataTypesOnBothSidesOfEqualityRule.RuleId,
    DataTypesOnBothSidesOfEqualityRule.RuleDisplayName,
    Description = DataTypesOnBothSidesOfEqualityRule.RuleDisplayName,
    Category = Constants.Performance,
    RuleScope = SqlRuleScope.Element)]
public sealed class DataTypesOnBothSidesOfEqualityRule : SqlCodeAnalysisRule
{
    public const string RuleId = Constants.RuleNameSpace + "SRP0016";
    public const string RuleDisplayName = "Data types on both sides of an equality check should be the same in the where clause. (Sargeable)";
    public const string Message = "{0} {1} data types on both sides of an equality do not match in the where clause.";
    private static StringComparer _comparer = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
    private readonly FunctionChain functionChain = new FunctionChain();
    #region built in function data types
    private static IDictionary<string, string> _functions = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        /*Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)*/
        { "SYSDATETIME", "datetime2" },
        { "SYSDATETIMEOFFSET", "datetimeoffset" },
        { "SYSUTCDATETIME", "datetime2" },
        { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "datetime" },
        { "GETDATE", "datetime" },
        { "GETUTCDATE", "datetime" },
        { "DATENAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "DATEPART", "int" },
        { "DAY", "int" },
        { "MONTH", "int" },
        { "YEAR", "int" },
        { "DATEFROMPARTS", "date" },
        { "DATETIME2FROMPARTS", "datetime2" },
        { "DATETIMEFROMPARTS", "datetime" },
        { "DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS", "datetimeoffset" },
        { "SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS", "smalldatetime" },
        { "TIMEFROMPARTS", "time" },
        { "DATEDIFF", "int" },
        { "DATEDIFF_BIG", "bigint" },
        { "ISDATE", "int" },
        /* Mathematical Functions (Transact-SQL)*/
        { "ACOS", "float" },
        { "ASIN", "float" },
        { "ATAN", "float" },
        { "ATN2", "float" },
        { "COS", "float" },
        { "COT", "float" },
        { "EXP", "float" },
        { "LOG", "float" },
        { "LOG10", "float" },
        { "PI", "float" },
        { "POWER", "float" },
        { "RAND", "float" },
        //{ "ROUND", "" }, completely unable to figure out how to map these. leaving commented here to mark that in case someone else figures it out
        //{ "SIGN", "" },
        { "SIN", "float" },
        { "SQRT", "float" },
        { "SQUARE", "float" },
        { "TAN", "float" },
        /*String Functions (Transact-SQL)*/
        { "ASCII", "int" },
        { "CHAR", "char" },
        { "DIFFERENCE", "int" },
        { "FORMAT", "nvarchar" },
        { "QUOTENAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "SOUNDEX", "varchar" },
        { "SPACE", "varchar" },
        { "STR", "varchar" },
        { "STRING_ESCAPE", "nvarchar" },
        { "UNICODE", "int" },
        /* System Functions (Transact-SQL)*/
        { "HOST_ID", "char" },
        { "HOST_NAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "ISNUMERIC", "int" },
        { "NEWID", "uniqueidentifier" },
        { "NEWSEQUENTIALID", "uniqueidentifier" },
        { "ROWCOUNT_BIG", "bigint" },
        { "SESSION_CONTEXT", "sql_variant" },
        { "SESSION_ID", "nvarchar" },
        { "XACT_STATE", "smallint" },
        /*Metadata Functions (Transact-SQL)*/
        { "APP_NAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "APPLOCK_MODE", "nvarchar" },
        { "APPLOCK_TEST", "smallint" },
        { "ASSEMBLYPROPERTY", "sql_variant" },
        { "COL_LENGTH", "smallint" },
        { "COL_NAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "COLUMNPROPERTY", "int" },
        { "DATABASEPROPERTYEX", "sql_variant" },
        { "DB_ID", "int" },
        { "DB_NAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "FILE_ID", "smallint" },
        { "FILE_IDEX", "int" },
        { "FILE_NAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "FILEGROUP_ID", "int" },
        { "FILEGROUP_NAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "FILEGROUPPROPERTY", "int" },
        { "FILEPROPERTY", "int" },
        { "FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY", "int" },
        { "FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY", "int" },
        { "INDEX_COL", "nvarchar" },
        { "INDEXKEY_PROPERTY", "int" },
        { "INDEXPROPERTY", "int" },
        { "OBJECT_DEFINITION", "nvarchar" },
        { "OBJECT_ID", "int" },
        { "OBJECT_NAME", "sysname" },
        { "OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME", "sysname" },
        { "OBJECTPROPERTY", "int" },
        { "OBJECTPROPERTYEX", "sql_variant" },
        { "ORIGINAL_DB_NAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "PARSENAME", "nchar" },
        { "SCHEMA_ID", "int" },
        { "SCHEMA_NAME", "sysname" },
        { "SCOPE_IDENTITY", "numeric" },
        { "SERVERPROPERTY", "sql_variant" },
        { "STATS_DATE", "datetime" },
        { "TYPE_ID", "int" },
        { "TYPE_NAME", "sysname" },
        { "TYPEPROPERTY", "int" },
        /*Security Functions (Transact-SQL)*/
        { "CERTENCODED", "varbinary" },
        { "CERTPRIVATEKEY", "varbinary" },
        { "CURRENT_USER", "sysname" },
        { "DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID", "int" },
        { "HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME", "int" },
        { "IS_MEMBER", "int" },
        { "IS_ROLEMEMBER", "int" },
        { "IS_SRVROLEMEMBER", "int" },
        { "ORIGINAL_LOGIN", "sysname" },
        { "PERMISSIONS", "int" },
        { "PWDCOMPARE", "int" },
        { "PWDENCRYPT", "varbinary" },
        { "SESSION_USER", "nvarchar" },
        { "SUSER_ID", "int" },
        { "SUSER_SID", "varbinary" },
        { "SUSER_SNAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "SYSTEM_USER", "nchar" },
        { "SUSER_NAME", "nvarchar" },
        { "USER_ID", "int" },
        { "USER_NAME", "nvarchar" }
    };
    #endregion

    public DataTypesOnBothSidesOfEqualityRule()
    {

        SupportedElementTypes = new[] { ModelSchema.Procedure, ModelSchema.View, ModelSchema.ScalarFunction, ModelSchema.TableValuedFunction };
    }

    public override IList<SqlRuleProblem> Analyze(SqlRuleExecutionContext ruleExecutionContext)
    {
        var problems = new List<SqlRuleProblem>();
        var sqlObj = ruleExecutionContext.ModelElement; //proc / view / function

        try
        {
            if (sqlObj != null)
            {
                var fragment = ruleExecutionContext.ScriptFragment;

                //get the combined parameters and declare variables into one searchable list
                var variablesVisitor = new VariablesVisitor();
                fragment.AcceptChildren(variablesVisitor);
                var variables = variablesVisitor.GetVariables();

                var selectStatementVisitor = new SelectStatementVisitor();
                fragment.Accept(selectStatementVisitor);
                foreach (var select in selectStatementVisitor.Statements)
                {
                    var query = select.QueryExpression as QuerySpecification;
                    if (query != null && query.WhereClause != null)
                    {
                        var booleanComparisonVisitor = new BooleanComparisonVisitor();
                        query.WhereClause.Accept(booleanComparisonVisitor);

                        foreach (var comparison in booleanComparisonVisitor.Statements)
                        {
                            var datatype1 = GetDataType(sqlObj, query, comparison.FirstExpression, variables);
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(datatype1)) { continue; }

                            var datatype2 = GetDataType(sqlObj, query, comparison.SecondExpression, variables);
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(datatype2)) { continue; }

                            //when checking the numeric literal I am not sure if it is a bit or tinyint.
                            if ((_comparer.Equals(datatype1, "bit") && _comparer.Equals(datatype2, "tinyint")) || (_comparer.Equals(datatype1, "tinyint") && _comparer.Equals(datatype2, "bit"))) { continue; }

                            if (!_comparer.Equals(datatype1, datatype2))
                            {
                                string msg = string.Format(Message, sqlObj.ObjectType.Name, RuleUtils.GetElementName(ruleExecutionContext, sqlObj));
                                problems.Add(new SqlRuleProblem(msg, sqlObj, comparison));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: PROPERLY LOG THIS ERROR
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            //throw;
        }

        return problems;
    }

    private string GetDataType(TSqlObject sqlObj, QuerySpecification query, ScalarExpression expression, IList<VariableView> variables)
    {
        if (expression is ColumnReferenceExpression)
        {
            return GetColumnDataType(sqlObj, query, expression);
        }
        else if (expression is StringLiteral)
        {
            var stringLiteral = expression as StringLiteral;
            if (stringLiteral.IsNational)
            {
                return "nvarchar";
            }
            else
            {
                return "varchar";
            }
        }
        else if (expression is IntegerLiteral)
        {
            long val = long.Parse(((IntegerLiteral)expression).Value);

            if (val >= 0 && val <= 255) // to bit or not to bit? NFC.
            {
                return "tinyint";
            }
            else if (val >= -32768 && val <= 32768)
            {
                return "smallint";
            }
            else if (val >= -2147483648 && val <= 2147483648)
            {
                return "int";
            }
            else if (val >= -9223372036854775808 && val <= 9223372036854775807)
            {
                return "bigint";
            }
            //technically this may not be accurate. as sql sever will interpret literal ints as different types 
            //depending upon how large they are. smallint, tinyint, etc... Unless I mimic their same value behavior.
            return "int";
        }
        else if (expression is CastCall)
        {
            var castCall = expression as CastCall;

            return castCall.DataType.Name.Identifiers.First().Value;
        }
        else if (expression is VariableReference)
        {
            var variable = variables.FirstOrDefault(v => _comparer.Equals(v.Name, ((VariableReference)expression).Name));
            if (variable != null)
            {
                return variable.DataType;
            }
        }
        else if (expression is FunctionCall)
        {
            //TIM C: sigh, this does not work for all functions. the api does not allow for me to look up built in functions. nor does it allow me to get the 
            //data types of parameters, so I am not able to type ALL functions like DATEADD, the parameter could be a column, string literal, variable, function etc...
            var function = expression as FunctionCall;
            if (_functions.ContainsKey(function.FunctionName.Value))
            {
                return _functions[function.FunctionName.Value];
            }
        }
        else if (expression is BinaryExpression)
        {
            var binaryExpression = expression as BinaryExpression;

            var datatype1 = GetDataType(sqlObj, query, binaryExpression.FirstExpression, variables);
            if (datatype1 != null) { return datatype1; }
            return GetDataType(sqlObj, query, binaryExpression.SecondExpression, variables);
        }
        else if (expression is ScalarSubquery)
        {
            var scalarQuery = ((ScalarSubquery)expression).QueryExpression as QuerySpecification;
            var selectElement = scalarQuery.SelectElements.First();

            return GetDataType(sqlObj, scalarQuery, ((SelectScalarExpression)selectElement).Expression, variables);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unknown expression");
        }


        return null;
    }

    private string GetColumnDataType(TSqlObject sqlObj, QuerySpecification query, ScalarExpression expression)
    {
        var column = expression as ColumnReferenceExpression;
        var tables = new List<NamedTableReference>();

        var namedTableVisitor = new NamedTableReferenceVisitor();
        query.FromClause.AcceptChildren(namedTableVisitor);

        if (column.MultiPartIdentifier.Identifiers.Count == 2)
        {
            tables.AddRange(namedTableVisitor.Statements.Where(x => x.Alias?.Value == column.MultiPartIdentifier.Identifiers[0].Value));
        }
        else
        {
            //they did NOT use a two part name, so logic dictates that this column SHOULD only appear once in the list of tables, but we will have to search all of the tables.
            tables.AddRange(namedTableVisitor.Statements);
        }

        var referencedTables = sqlObj.GetReferenced().Where(x => x.ObjectType == Table.TypeClass && tables.Any(t => x.Name.CompareTo(t.SchemaObject.Identifiers)));

        foreach (var referencedTable in referencedTables)
        {
            string fullColumnName = referencedTable.Name.ToString() + ".[" + column.MultiPartIdentifier.Identifiers.Last().Value + "]";

            var retColumn = referencedTable.GetReferencedRelationshipInstances(Table.Columns).FirstOrDefault(p => _comparer.Equals(p.ObjectName.ToString(), fullColumnName));

            if (retColumn != null)
            {
                var dataType = retColumn.Object.GetReferenced(Column.DataType)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

                return dataType.Name.Parts.First();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The variables visitor:

```
internal enum VariableViewType
{
    Parameter,
    Declare
}
internal class VariableView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public VariableViewType Type { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
        {
            return $"{this.Type} {this.Name} {this.DataType}";
        }
        return base.ToString();
    }
}

internal class VariablesVisitor : TSqlFragmentVisitor
{
    public IList<DeclareVariableStatement> DeclareVariables { get; private set; }
    public IList<ProcedureParameter> ProcedureParameters { get; private set; }

    public VariablesVisitor()
    {
        DeclareVariables = new List<DeclareVariableStatement>();
        ProcedureParameters = new List<ProcedureParameter>();
    }
    public override void ExplicitVisit(DeclareVariableStatement node)
    {
        DeclareVariables.Add(node);
    }
    public override void ExplicitVisit(ProcedureParameter node)
    {
        ProcedureParameters.Add(node);
    }

    public IList<VariableView> GetVariables()
    {
        var ret = new List<VariableView>();
        foreach (var statements in DeclareVariables)
        {
            foreach (var declare in statements.Declarations)
            {
                ret.Add(new VariableView()
                {
                    Name = declare.VariableName.Value,
                    DataType = declare.DataType.Name.Identifiers.Last().Value,
                    Type = VariableViewType.Declare
                });

            }
        }
        foreach (var parameter in ProcedureParameters)
        {
            ret.Add(new VariableView()
            {
                Name = parameter.VariableName.Value,
                DataType = parameter.DataType.Name.Identifiers.Last().Value,
                Type = VariableViewType.Parameter
            });
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Other visitors:

```
internal class SelectStatementVisitor : TSqlFragmentVisitor
{
    public IList<SelectStatement> Statements { get; private set; }
    public SelectStatementVisitor()
    {
        Statements = new List<SelectStatement>();
    }
    public override void ExplicitVisit(SelectStatement node)
    {
        Statements.Add(node);
    }
}
internal class BooleanComparisonVisitor : TSqlFragmentVisitor
{
    public IList<BooleanComparisonExpression> Statements { get; private set; }


    public BooleanComparisonVisitor()
    {
        Statements = new List<BooleanComparisonExpression>();
    }

    public override void ExplicitVisit(BooleanComparisonExpression node)
    {
        Statements.Add(node);
    }
}
```

The named table visitor:

```
internal class NamedTableReferenceVisitor : TSqlFragmentVisitor
{
    public IList<NamedTableReference> Statements { get; private set; }


    public NamedTableReferenceVisitor()
    {
        Statements = new List<NamedTableReference>();
    }

    public override void ExplicitVisit(NamedTableReference node)
    {
        Statements.Add(node);
    }
}
```